# enviar email com Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Criei o seguinte Model com o Nodejs:

```
'use strict'

function UserDAO(model) {
    this.model = model;
}

UserDAO.prototype.email = function(callback) {

//TESTE de email
var filePath = 'services/content/test.html';
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('config');
var mail = require('../services/email.service');

//TESTE de email
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, content)
{
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to read email file template html, err = ' + err);
        callback('Failed to read email file template html, err = ' + err);
    } 
    else {
        var url = config.get('smtpConfig.redirectUrl') + '/#/novo-usuario?token=' + '123456'
        var rendered = content.toString().replace('#link#', 'teste.com.br');
        mail.send('eduardo.massami@yahoo.com.br',
            'Bem-vindo',
            'Acesse o link: ',
            rendered, function (err, info)
            {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err)
                }
                else {
                    console.log('E-Mail enviado: ' + info);

                    var retorno = { message: 'Usuário criado com sucesso!' };
                    callback(null, retorno);
                }
        });
     }   
});
//FIM TESTE email
}

module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var User = mongoose.model('User', {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true}, 
        email: {type: String, required: true},
        ra: {type: Number, required: false},
        tipo: {type: String, required: true}
    });
    return new UserDAO(User);
}
```

O email.service está da seguinte forma:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer"); //para enviar emails
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var config = require('config');

function enviarEmail (to, subject, text, html, callback) {

//console.log("entrou no email.service.js");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: config.get('smtpConfig.host'),
    port: config.get('smtpConfig.port'),
    secure: config.get('smtpConfig.secure'),
    auth: {
        user: config.get('smtpConfig.auth.user'),
        pass: config.get('smtpConfig.auth.pass')
    }
}));

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: config.get('smtpConfig.from'),
    to: to, 
    subject: subject, 
    text: text, 
    html: html
};

//verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        transporter.close();
    } else {
        console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
        //send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info)
        {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }
            callback(null, info);
        });
    }
});
}

exports.send = function (to, subject, text, html, callback) {
  return enviarEmail(to, subject, text, html, callback);  
}
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

Server is ready to take our messages
{ [Error: Mail command failed: 553 From address not verified ]
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '553 From address not verified - 
  responseCode: 553 }
{ [Error: Mail command failed: 553 From address not verified]
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '553 From address not verified,
  responseCode: 553 }

Answer (score -1):

Eduardo,

Testa dessa forma em um JS separado e ve se resolve.

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var conta = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.seudominio.com.br',
  port: '587',
  auth: {
    user: 'email@seudominio.com.br',
    pass: 'suaSenha'
  },
  secure: false,
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

var enviarSenha = function(nome, email, callback){
  var config = {
    from: 'Nome remetente <email@seudominio.com.br>', // Quem está mandando
    to: nome + ' <' + email + '>', // Para quem o e-mail deve chegar
    subject: 'Recuperação de Senha', // O assunto
    html: '<strong>Olá ' + nome + '!</strong>' // O HTMl do nosso e-mail
  };
  conta.sendMail(config, function(err, info){
    callback(err, info);
  });
};
```

User e pass é usuário e senha do e-mail do remetente para que não de erro no envio, pois alguns provedores não deixam enviar sem essa autenticação.